# I'm trying to find the Taylor expansion of sqrt(x) of order 5 in the point 1 in a simple way

Tags: taylor-expansion

The trivial thing is to differentiate the expression 5 times and substitute in the formula.

Is there any way to simplify what I wrote in the title out?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Another option is using [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=taylor+series+of+sqrt(x)+in+1), depending on what you're trying to do. If you don't need a formal proof, wolframalpha is your friend

Comment: @vrugtehagel Haha unfortuneatly i'm not allowed to use Wolframalpha during the test. I'm looking for ways to simplify the Taylor expansions of certain functions

Comment: In that case I'm afraid you'll just have to do it the oldfashioned way, calculating the derivative 5 times. Sometimes, when expressions are a little more complicated like [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1219974/is-there-an-easier-way-of-finding-a-taylor-series-than-just-straight-computing-t) or [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/410039/what-is-the-easiest-most-efficient-way-to-find-the-taylor-series-expansion-of-e), there's something smart you can do to make it easier, but $\sqrt{x}$ is too basic for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to find regularities in the derivatives of $\sqrt x$. Notice for $n\geq 2$ the $n$-th derivative of $\sqrt x$ is

$$(-1)^n \frac{(2n-3)!!}{2^n} x^{-\frac{2n-1}2}.$$

I found it by writing down the first three derivatives and by looking closely. I still think that deriving five times may be the faster way. $\sqrt x$ has not so complicated derivatives, especially when written as $x^{\frac12}$.